# Birthday attacks vs. Preimage attacks

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, cryptography, birthday

I am trying to understand why a preimage attack is different than a birthday attack.

Following the general description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) (sorry if that is a poor source?):

- A preimage attack is where an output $y$ of a hash $h$ is known, and the task is to find some input $x$ such that $h(x) = y$
- A birthday attack is where the task is to find any two inputs $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $h(x_1) = h(x_2)$

It seems to me that a preimage attack is the same as a birthday attack, it's just that $x_2$ is effectively fixed ahead of time. Said another way, I don't see how varying *both* inputs to $h$ will yield an output collision so much more efficiently. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You should look the birthday attack Wiki section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Understanding_the_problem, do you unterstand it?
See also the main article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @gammatester I've read both of those pages a couple of times, so I _believe_ I do, but perhaps not? Such is the problem with these situations.

Comment: If you take the [Birthday problem at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), the preimage attack is like the variant [Same birthday as you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Same_birthday_as_you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the birthday attack, you can save the results of guessing $h(x_i)=y_i$. The more outputs you have, the easier it is to match one of them. For example, after $i$ guesses the problem is to find $x_{i+1}$ such that $h(x_{i+1})\in \{y_1,y_2,...y_i\}$ whereas in the preimage attack you still have to find $h(x)\in \{y\}$.

Comment: Okay, I think that's my answer. The [birthday attack Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) refers to _pairs_ over and over. It wasn't clear (at least to me) that outputs are retained while searching for a match.